# rebuild app in xcode5 and change graphic style

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5

i've rebuild a old app code for my company and after correct all the errors for the updated xcode5, when i launch the app on my devices it has a different appearance.
In specific the old one are in old iphone style and now, without make grafics change(i think), the theme in iOS7.

i'm sorry if the question is too simple but i'm very newbie in iphone develop

Comment: maybe because now does not xcode5  permit to create ios6 theme app?

Comment: If you are building using `xcode 5`+ to an iOS7 device then your app will use the new iOS7 look and feel, what did you think would happen when you updated?

Comment: i don't know, i've change many thinks. I've use xcode5 and iphone 5 and 4s with iOS7 but if i download the old app from the store on the same phone the app is in old style

Comment: That's because your old app was built with an xcode below xcode 5 and your new app is being built with xcode 5 and above. Apps built with xcode 5+ will have the new iOS7 look and feel to it when building to devices running iOS7 so it will use the new flat UI whether you like it are not. You don't need to have done anything except move from xcode 4.* to xcode 5.

Answer (score 1):

If you build your application with a `pre-xcode 5 IDE` then it will retain the `iOS6` look and feel, even when you download the old version of your app that is on the app store to an `iOS 7` running device.

However there are some UI Elements that you have zero control over such as the `UIAlertViews` and `UIActionSheets` these will appear with the `iOS 7` look and feel no matter what you do.

Once you start building your applications though with `xcode 5` and above your application will now start to use the look and feel of `iOS 7` so as soon as you do a new build with `xcode 5` and above your applications will look different even if you haven't changed anything.

Note that from the [1st of February 201](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172013a)4 all Apps submitted to the Apple Apps Store must be built using at least `xcode 5` and must be optimized for `iOS7`. So if you want to provide anymore updates to the Apple App store you will need to optimize your application to use `iOS7` properly. Here is the [Apple iOS7 Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/index.html) that you may want to read.